# How to daisy-chain monitors (with DisplayPort) from Thunderbolt USB Type-C ports, like the new 2016 Macbook Pro?

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, thunderbolt

I know this has been asked before, but given the new Macbooks October 2016, and all these new Type-C USB/Thunderbolt ports that supposedly can do everything, I want to ask again, **how is it possible to hook up two (DELL 2515H) monitors with DisplayPort 1.2?**

Most notebooks I'm looking at to buy, they all have HDMI, newer models do not have mDP port anymore. But they all have USB-Type-C.

I am looking at a bunch of notebooks and they all have the USB Type-C port (Thunderbolt 3). But how do I physically make the connection? I know the wires are the same, so it should work just like that. **Correct?**

My observations:

1. The miniDisplayport-Displayport cable won't work, the plug is different.
2. There is no cable (at least I can't find it) that goes from Type-C----Displayport.
3. There is no hub/adapter for Type-C port that offers a Displayport or miniDisplayport plug. There are hubs, but only with HDMI.
4. You can't use the HDMI port of either the Notebook or the Hub, HDMI doesn't support miniDisplayPort 1.2 (needed to daisy-chain). **Is that correct?**

So how do you do it?

Again, this has been asked before, but thanks for clarifying.

Comment: USB Type-C is not Thunderbolt as far as I know and if you can't find an adapter you probably can't. Try to look for a way to attach one of those hubs/adapters?

Comment: @Seth AFAIK USB Type-C is everything: USB 3.1, TB 3, "alternate modes" such as display port, HDMI --- the new Macbook is even charged via the same Type-C port. However, the port itself isn't enough, it has to specifically support those "alternate modes". And that depends on the mainboard/manufacturer. I was able to find a USB Type-C to Displayport cable last night, made by Pluggable for 30 bucks.

Comment: The USB type C **PLUG** supports a lot. The electronic parts on both sides of the plug also need to support the same language. Sometimes that is not the case (e.g. when connected to a plimple USB controller).

Comment: USB-C is not the same as USB-C; some support [alternate modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Alternate_Mode_partner_specifications), some don't. Look **very** closely.

Answer (score 1):

Every display I have seen that supports daisy chaining will have a full sized DisplayPort output that is clearly labeled as the output.  Input will have to be from some other port that talks the DisplayPort protocol.  This can be USB-C, mini-DP, or a different full size DisplayPort port.

The host computer would have to support MST, the protocol for daisy chaining, as would the all but the last display in the chain.  The connection from the computer has to use the DisplayPort MST protocol which can be by USB-C, DisplayPort, or mini-DisplayPort.

> The miniDisplayport-Displayport cable won't work, the plug is different.
> There is no cable (at least I can't find it) that goes from Type-C----Displayport.

There's plenty of cables that will provide a DisplayPort from USB-C.
This may be a start.
https://www.startech.com/en-us/audio-video-products/display-and-video-adapters/usb-c-video-adapters?page=1&sort=relevance&filter_avoutput=displayport%20-%201.4

> There is no hub/adapter for Type-C port that offers a Displayport or
> miniDisplayport plug. There are hubs, but only with HDMI. You can't
> use the HDMI port of either the Notebook or the Hub, HDMI doesn't
> support miniDisplayPort 1.2 (needed to daisy-chain). Is that correct?

Connecting the DisplayPort to DisplayPort should be easy.
https://www.startech.com/en-us/cables/audio-video/displayport

Is there something Im missing?

Answer (score 1):

Daisy-chaining displays on macOS computers is not possible with DisplayPort because macOS does not support the MST protocol.  In trying to find a definitive source for this the best I could find for it was this: https://us.targus.com/blogs/discover-targus/macbook-doesnt-support-multi-stream-transport

Without MST support daisy-chaining displays is not possible.

> The miniDisplayport-Displayport cable won't work, the plug is
> different.

Even with a cable from output on the first display to the second it will not work in anything bur mirror mode because macOS does not support MST.

> There is no cable (at least I can't find it) that goes from
> Type-C----Displayport.

They do exist though they may be difficult to find, you may have to order the cable online.  Here's one example of a source: https://www.belkin.com/us/usb-c-to-displayport-cable/p/p-b2b103-06/

> There is no hub/adapter for Type-C port that
> offers a Displayport or miniDisplayport plug. There are hubs, but only
> with HDMI.

Any Thunderbolt/USB-C hub should support DisplayPort from the USB-C ports.  One example from OWC: https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/owc-thunderbolt-dock
The hub will still only allow one display per USB-C port on the computer because macOS does not support MST.

> You can't use the HDMI port of either the Notebook or the
> Hub, HDMI doesn't support miniDisplayPort 1.2 (needed to daisy-chain).
> Is that correct?

HDMI does not support daisy-chaining.  DisplayPort allows for daisy-chaining but this is optional using MST and, again, macOS does not support MST daisy-chaining.

> Again, this has been asked before, but thanks for clarifying.

Yes, it has been asked before, and answered before.  This was bumped to the top toady so I offer an updated answer relevant to products available today.

The short of it is that macOS does not support MST, and MST is required for daisy-chained DisplayPort displays.  This is not a hardware limitation as people have been able to get Apple hardware to daisy-chain displays with Windows and Linux.  With this knowledge there is an implied workaround for advanced users where this is an important function.  The other major concern about not finding the right kinds of hubs, cables, adapters, etc. is merely a matter of knowing how DisplayPort works and it's relationship to Thunderbolt and USB-C.  The cables are available but it does require knowing what to look for and how the DisplayPort protocol works.